# Expose Values of Extensions via SAML 2.0 Using Azure Active Directory as Identity Provider

Tags: azure, saml-2.0, netsuite, azure-active-directory

I am trying to configure SP-initiated SSO using SAML 2.0 between Azure Active Directory and NetSuite OpenAir. OpenAir requests a company ID and a user ID that are not part of the Azure Active Directory schema, so I added the necessary fields as extensions using the method at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/archive/2014/03/06/extend-azure-active-directory-schema-using-graph-api-preview.aspx

I now have the extension fields populated in AAD (one for UserID and one for CompanyID) but I do not know how to edit the Federation Metadata to enable them to be requested and asserted via SAML 2.0. I also don't know what URI to use to get the actual value included in the response.

This is the solution I've chosen for SP-initiated SSO with AAD as IdP, if you have another suggestion please let me know. I've been looking here, on MSDN, and on various documentation sites and blogs without success for about a week.